# jQuery Inline Confirmation (delete) - Implementation Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement this inline delete confirmation plugin for jquery. Here is the sample code:

```
//sample code taken from plugin on GitHub: 
//https://github.com/fredwu/jquery-inline-confirmation
$("a.delete").inlineConfirmation({
  confirm: "<a href='#' class='confirm-yes'>Yes</a>",
  cancel: "<a href='#' class='confirm-no'>No</a>",
  separator: " | ",
  reverse: true,
  bindsOnEvent: "hover",
  confirmCallback: function(action) {
    action.parent().fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Appending that to any selector will display the delete or cancel buttons, but I need to show this option ON CLICK.

So my original code is this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) { 
            $( '#mytable button').click( function( event ) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 


            if ( ! confirm( 'Are you sure you want to continue' ) ) 
                    return; 

    var $button = $(this);
    var nonce = $( this ).attr('data-nonce');
    var rowID = $( this ).attr('value'); 
    var file = $( this ).attr('file'); 

            var data = { }

            $.post( 
                    ajaxurl, 
                    data,
                    function ( response ) { });
        }); 
});
```

The plugin allows for a 'confirmCallback', and I need my code to be executed upon confirm click, rather than immediately like it is currently.  I am still learning jQuery so this may be a simple issue.  Just need to know how to customize this so its something like this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) { 
$( '#mytable button').click( function( event ) { 
$(this).inlineConfirmation({
confirmCallback: (?? WHAT DO I PUT HERE??)
});
```

if confirmed then run my code (which would be the confirmCallback.  How do I do this?
    .post ... etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Appending that to any selector will display the delete or cancel buttons, but I need to show this option ON CLICK.

Change this:

```
bindsOnEvent: "hover",
```

To this: (although the documentation says that this is the default)

```
bindsOnEvent: "click",
```

And add a callback function like so:

```
confirmCallback: function (a) {
     // write your code here.
}
```

So all in all:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#mytable button').inlineConfirmation({
         bindsOnEvent: "click",
         confirmCallback: function($button) {
             var nonce = $button.attr('data-nonce');
             var rowID = $button.attr('value'); 
             var file = $button.attr('file'); 

             var data = {};

             $.post( 
                ajaxurl, 
                data,
                function ( response ) { }
             );
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: but what is the function(action)?   I need it to execute the .post code I have.

Comment: Referring to `jQuery.post`? Just put that code (`$.post("path", {data:"data"})`) inside the callback.

Comment: That seems to work, but now none of my vars are recognized, maybe it is because they are placed within the confirmCallback?  Where should the VARs be?

Comment: If you already have a function you can call, you may specify `confirmCallback: yourFunctionNameHere`. and outside of the `.ready` function you can have `function yourFunctionNameHere() { /* $.post(...) */ }`

Comment: I never had a function name, Its within <script> tags.  I most of my code above so you better understand what I mean.  Thank you so far for you help, the inline confirmation is working but it wont .post now.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've updated my answer with all the code together.

Comment: Thank you a million! Anyway I can reach you outside of stackoverflow to hire you for some simple code?